# How to change gem installation directory on Mac?

Tags: rubygems

Hi my administrator installed ruby and gem on `/usr/local/bin/gem`. How can i change this installation directory to a custom folder? Because i cant do the following action `gem install sass`. No permission. Pleas help me on this guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set your `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH`

`GEM_PATH` specifies the locations where gems is to be found.

GEM_HOME specifies the location where the gems will be installed.

```
export GEM_HOME=<new location>
```

But if you do not want to change the Path and just want to install a few gems, you can also do the following:

```
gem install --install-dir /path_to_new_directory my-gem-name
```

example:

```
gem install --install-dir /Users/xyz/Desktop sass
```

will install rails on the Desktop

Comment: Is GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME have to be different path?